# Rating system assistance

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using a rating script from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/building-a-5-star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-and-php/

But I want it to upload the ratings to a database and stop a person from voting the same picture all the time.

This is my script to upload and set a cookie:

```
<?php 
// Get id and voted value
$id = $_POST['widget_id'];
preg_match('/star_([1-5]{1})/', $_POST['clicked_on'], $match);
$vote = $match[1];

// Connect to database and find the row which have the id
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE id = '$id'");

while ($getdata = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
    $total_votes = $getdata['total_votes'];
    $total_value = $getdata['total_value'];

    // See if the votes and value is 0 and if it aint it update the database and if it is were creating a new row
    if ($total_votes != 0 && $total_value != 0) {
            $total_votes++;
            mysql_query("UPDATE ratings SET total_votes = '$total_votes' WHERE 
                         id = '$id'");
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ratings (id, total_votes, total_value) 
                 VALUES ('$id', '1', '$vote')");
}

// Sets the cookie
$value = $id;
// Send a cookie that expires in 24 hours
setcookie($id, $value, time() + 3600 * 24); 
?>
```

But if the user already has voted he can still vote so I need someway to check if he has the cookie and a way to get the data from the mysql table and send it to the user.

Comment: You found a free script and want free support? Have you looked at any of the free documentation or free tutorials?

Comment: Please take a look at [PHP's PDO functions](http://php.net/pdo), MySQL is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect syntax...

```
$total_votes = $total_votes . +1;
```

This will add 1 to `$total_votes`

```
$total_votes++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you set $value to be the same as id.

```
 $value = $id;
```

And here you make a cookie called the value of the variable $id which makes a dynamic name of the  cookie.

```
setcookie($id,$value, time()+3600*24);
```

To make a cookie always set a static name

```
//create cookie
setcookie('widget_id',$id, time()+3600*24); // $value is useless

//read cookie
echo $_COOKIE['widget_id']; //prints the cookie

// unset cookie
unset($_COOKIE['widget_id'];);
```

Comment: But the problem with your code is that it is only saving the latest voted item and not every item that the person is voting

Comment: You could seperate them with a semicolon and when you want to read them split them. Or save an ID in a cookie which links to the database and fetch all rows matching the id.

Comment: But then the problem would be that people only can vote once but they should be able to vote once every day

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got the function to check if the cookie is set done so now i only need to get the data from the mysql table and output to the javascript

Here are my code

```
    <?php 
// Get id and voted value
$id = $_POST['widget_id'];
preg_match('/star_([1-5]{1})/', $_POST['clicked_on'], $match);
$vote = $match[1];
// Connect to database and find the row which have the id
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE id = '$id'");

if (isset($_COOKIE[$id])) {
echo 'cookie exist';
exit;
} else {

while ($getdata = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
    $total_votes = $getdata['total_votes'];
    $total_value = $getdata['total_value'];

    // See if the votes and value is 0 and if it aint it update the database and if it is were creating a new row
    if ($total_votes != 0 && $total_value != 0) {
            $total_votes++;
            mysql_query("UPDATE ratings SET total_votes = '$total_votes' WHERE 
                         id = '$id'");
} else {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ratings (id, total_votes, total_value) 
                 VALUES ('$id', '1', '$vote')");
}

// Send a cookie that expires in 24 hours
setcookie($id, $id, time() + 3600 * 24); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't keep track of whether or not a user has voted on a particular thing with a cookie.

Instead, you should check your database to make sure the user hasn't voted on that particular thing before submitting the INSERT vote query.

If the user has already voted, perhaps perform an UPDATE instead of an INSERT to change their vote to the new value.

So you would be checking like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ratings
WHERE userid=:userid
```

You will benefit from using PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to bind necessary parameters and can then easily check how many rows are returned (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

If 1 row is returned, the user has already voted.  Then you can update the vote with the new vote value.

If 0 rows are returned, the user has not already voted.  Then you can do the insert like you do in your code above.

If more than 1 row is returned, then multiple votes have been inserted already and you need to delete all but 1 of those votes.

I suggest adding a column for the individual pages / objects so you can use this functionality.

Comment: @ArtaexMedia Actually it is, this is his question:  "I need someway to check if he has the cookie and a way to get the data from the mysql table and send it to the user."

Comment: the users are anonymouse so i can't do it like that and i won't be logging ip's to check if the user has voted because on many schools and so students get the same ip so only one can rate